# keeping order rows saved to calculate rank and percentile

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, locking

we have a large table, around 12M records, everyday at midnight,
we run a query to sort all rows by a certain criteria and save the order in a column.

the reason we do that is because we have a request to the server that servers the order of this record and the percentile it's in

for example, if the queried row was ranked 1000, it should return 1000 and the percentile will be top 1% for example, and this endpoint is very active and gets thousands of requests per minute

so long time ago, we wrote the following query that runs in a background job at midnight:

```
set @x = 0; 
update ranking r
INNER JOIN (select @x:=@x+1 newposition,id
FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT userId from ranking)
ORDER BY points DESC) uw ON userId = uw.id
set r.overall_rank = uw.newposition;
```

so the query works perfectly fine, all rows are now ordered per points in the users column and we can server the values in the request in a speedy manner

the issue is this query it's self is taking few minutes to execute, and it's locking the users table while reading, and every time the job runs in the background, all server requests start to take too long

I'm not sure if the solution to this can be done at the database level or we can do something from the server code it's self, if you can give me any tips, that would be much appreciated

Comment: Caution:  ` SELECT  @x:=...` is deprecated and will be removed from MySQL at some point.

Comment: In "WHERE id IN (SELECT userId", is id::userid a 1:1 mapping?  Or 1:many?  Or many:1?  Also, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: See also the Windowing functions `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: @RickJames, yes the mapping is 1:1 on this table, I will check the Rank function never heard of it

Answer (score 1):

I believe the table gets locked from reading while doing an update to the table happens because of the Concurrency model used by your MySQL database. The concurrency model used should be **Pessimistic concurrency model**. Where when one transaction is doing an update to a record, other transactions get locked from doing READ or WRITE on that same record, until that lock is released. This is called an Exclusive Lock. In that case server requests involving the **ranking** table will take too long, cause you are updating the whole table. So, all records on the **ranking** table will be on lock, until the update is complete.

Take the below example. NOTE: Syntax from SQL Server. MySQL syntax could be a little different.

1. Open 2 windows and try the practice example below.
2. Window 1 - Run the query below

   ```sql
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   UPDATE ranking SET overall_rank = 10 WHERE userid = 10
   ```
3. Window 2 - Try the 2 queries below

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM ranking WHERE userid = 10 
   -- should get hold without a result, because there is a lock from Window 1 Ongoing transaction.
   ```

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM ranking WHERE userid > 5 and userid < 10
   ```

   should get hold without a result, because there is a lock for the record which fell into this resultset, with userid = 2, from Window 1 Ongoing transaction.
4. Go to Window 1 Again

   ```sql
   COMMIT
   ```
5. Go to Window 2 and check those select queries. Those should have returned the result

##### Solution:

In SQL Server, this is very similar. By default SQL server has **Pessimistic concurrency model** with **READ COMMITTED** isolation level. And this is how the READ COMMITTED isolation level works. Using Exclusive locks to prevent DIRTY READS concurrency problem. This isolation level can change based on your application business and the nature to the more OPTIMISTIC way.

In Azure SQL, by default, they have **OPTIMISTIC concurrency model**. Where they have **READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT** isolation level. This means, instead READS are blocked by WRITES, they just use row **versioning**, so when there a WRITE is happening on a record, READS get the last committed version (a snapshot) of the same record. So, no locking is required to prevent DIRTY reads.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I'm not an expert with Databases so I will have to do some testing before I can achieve this, but can you change the concurrency model for one query only ?

Comment: To my understanding changing concurrency model is something that should done considering whole database level. Is just a question that your DBMS should think Pessimistic way (worst case scenario could happen) or Optimistic way (concurrency updates are possible but rare) based on your nature of the application. Which means it should done on Database level. Here is a link for [concurrency problems in RDBMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=design-concurrency-issues)